# Why do windows keep snapping back to the upper left corner? (windows 8.1)

Tags: windows-8.1

In Windows 8.1, pretty often, if I go to move a window, it will move back to the upper left corner of the screen (just like a "snap to grid" feature often works). I can drag it away from there, but releasing it lets it snap back to the upper left. Newly created windows also start there.

This behavior is not helpful. It presents most often when resuming from suspend, but it also occasionally happens while working.

There is one workaround I have found. If I open "Make the mouse easier to use" in the "Ease of Access Center" in the Control Panel, and toggle any setting twice (that is, returning it to the same settings as when I opened the panel), then click OK, the problem fixes itself for a while.

Additional factors that *could* contribute:

- I have an AMD graphics card
- I occasionally connect a second monitor. It is physically disconnected when not in use. It is configured to the right of the main monitor when it is connected.
- I use suspend daily.
- rebooting does **not** fix it.
- I use a wireless keyboard and mouse, both Logitech, with separate receivers. Reception is generally not a problem.
- This is **not** the behavior controlled by the Snap feature, it is completely different. (Snap feature lets you maximize windows by dragging them to the top of the screen, etc. This is not resizing, just always moving to the same spot against my will)

Any ideas what could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed. I assume it was fixed in a Windows update, but might have been a video card driver update. I never did find the root cause.